# Obtaining array item from WordPress revisions output

Tags: array

I am having trouble retrieving an array item from WordPress revisions array. I have Googled and no answer I have come across has worked so far. What I am trying to do is create a list of all Authors who have done revisions of a post so I can display this in a dashboard. The rest I can complete just having issues getting the item from the array.

```
$arrayz =  '[0]=>
  object(WP_Post)#4970 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(224)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-11-18 23:93:39"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2019-11-18 23:13:39"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(24) "New content added here"
        }';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arrayz);
echo '</pre>';
// Getting error here
echo $arrayz[0]["post_author"];
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: [Illegal string offset 'post_author' on line

Comment: Is this code exactly how you are running it? If so, then $arrayz is just a string. What is the output of var_dump? What if you `var_dump($arrayz[0])`?

Comment: I am running $revisions =  wp_get_post_revisions($post->ID); and then using var_dump($revisions); but in my snippet I just created an array with only one return.

Answer (score 1):

To get the post author ID you can try:

```
$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions($post->ID); 
//For first author
$first_author = $revisions[0]->post_author;
//to get all revision authors
foreach( $revisions as $revision ){
    echo $revision->post_author;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me in the loop!